# Reference for Poisson point process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm looking for a good reference book for **PPP** (**Poisson point process**) and the stochastic integration theory with regard to **PPP**.

I have tried "**Stochastic Differential Equations and Diffusion Process**" written by Shinzo Watanabe
&
the **lecture notes for Stochastic Analysis** written by Prof **Andreas Eberle**.

But I think they are both not strictly enough to introduce PPP in a mathematical way. (Indeed some conclusions seemed impossible under the former assumptions given in this two books!)

So I wonder if there is any notes or books which can provide a "strict" introduction of **PPP** and its stochastic integration theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Poisson Processes* by J.F.C. Kingman (Oxford University Press, 1993) is an excellent introduction.

A deeper dive can be found in  *Lectures on the Poisson Process* by G. Last and M. Penrose (Cambridge University Press, 2018).

Comment: Thank you for your recomendation ! !